# PHP: Explode data from string based on other string

Tags: php, string, split, delimiter, explode

I am trying to get the value of Split Parts.

My code is:

```
<?php 
$password = "03,10,05,07,17,23";

$string = "::3:8:1::5::2:9::::6:::4::::::0:";

$string = explode(':', $string);
```

How to do print $string by order of $password

$string[03],$string[10],$string[05],$string[07],$string[17],$string[23]

Result Need : 391540

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: update your question with your desired output please

Comment: Result : 391540  @Val

Comment: wow may i know what is the logic behind this ?, really your question doesnt have sufficient info to give your answer, please update your question with proper info

Comment: Result : 391540 @BunkerBoy

Comment: maybe you posted on wrong site?  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actualy i can print $string[0] .. $string[1].... but the question is how i can print $string by order using $password for exapmle $string[3],$string[10]....  sorry for my english @BunkerBoy

Comment: It's the right site thanks for your answer @Val

Comment: but after your explode if we see $string[3] =  8  not 3, so how your desired output start with 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you goes  [Live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5a53d906ac8c9432192f22624677372e72049fad)

```
$password = "03,10,05,07,17,23";

$string = "::3:8:1::5::2:9::::6:::4::::::0:";

$pass = explode(',', $password);
$code = explode(':', $string);

$result = '';
foreach ($pass as $pos) {
    $pos = ((int)$pos)-1;
    $result .= $code[$pos];
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: **Thank You, thats what i'm locking for** @Val